# How to modify cell content in tabs created with a script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a total beginner with App Script, but I can kind of understand the language, and paste together snippets of code that I grab here and there ;-)
By browsing the site I already found a way to create a menu item to trigger a function, and a way to duplicate a template tab and to rename each copy with data from a range in a data sheet (yay!).
Since my coding skills are quite basic, I am missing only one thing that I really can't find anywhere: how to change the value in cell A4 of the template copies and match it with the template copies.
The code I managed to put together, thanks to various threads, is this:

```html
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
        .addItem('Create New Tabs', 'TemplateDuplication')
        .addToUi()}
function TemplateDuplication()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      temp = ss.getSheetByName('Template'),
      all = ss.getSheetByName('Catalysts data'),
      sheets = ss.getSheets(),
      vals = all.getRange('a2:a').getValues();
  for (var i = 0, len = sheets.length, names = []; i < len; i++)
    names.push(sheets[i].getName());
  for (var i = vals.length-1; i > 0; i--)
  {
    var name = vals[i][0];
    if (name !='' && names.indexOf(name) == -1)
    {
      temp.activate();
      ss.duplicateActiveSheet()
      .setName(vals[i][0])
     
    }  }}
```

This works like a charm, but I would then have to enter each copy and change the value of cell A4 to the name of the freshly created copy. There has to be a better way!!

I hope the information provided is sufficient, I am not attaching the sheets because there's sensitive info in them, and I don't think it would be of any help anyway.

Thanks a lot and have a grand day!

Michele.

---

EDIT

Soooo, thanks to Yuri (remind me to pay you a beer), the code looks like this now:

```html
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
        .addItem('Create New Tabs', 'TemplateDuplication')
        .addToUi()}
function TemplateDuplication()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      temp = ss.getSheetByName('Template'),
      all = ss.getSheetByName('Catalysts data'),
      sheets = ss.getSheets(),
      vals = all.getRange('a1:a').getValues();
  var names = sheets.map(x => x.getName());
  for (var i = vals.length-1; i > 0; i--)
  {
    var name = vals[i][0];
    if (name !='' && names.indexOf(name) == -1)
    {
      temp.activate();
      ss.duplicateActiveSheet()
      .setName(vals[i][0])
      ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange("A4").setValue(name);
     
    }  }}
```

It does exactly what I need:

- creates a custom menu so I can run the script from the sheet (neat)
- It duplicates the "Template" tab and names them with the data provided in column A of the sheet "Catalysts data"
- It replaces the value in cell A4 of each duplicate with the same value of the tab name

This will save me hours of work, and I am overwhelmed with the help I received here.

Thanks to Yuri and Cooper for the answers provided!!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand you need to add one line in the end (right after `.setName(vals[i][0])`):

```
ss.getSheetByName(name).getRange("A4").setValue(name);
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot Yuri, it might seem simple for someone fluent, but I could have searched forever...

Answer (score 0):

```
function TemplateDuplication() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const temp = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  const all = ss.getSheetByName('Catalysts data');
  const shts = ss.getSheets().map(sh => sh.getName());
  const vals = all.getRange(2, 1, all.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  var names = [];
  vals.forEach((r,i) =>{
    if(!~names.indexOf(r[0])) {
      temp.copyTo(ss).setName(r[0]).getRange('A4').setValue(r[0]);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I used a lowercase t rather than an uppercase so change copyto to copyTo

Comment: Thanks a lot Cooper, I actually implemented Yuri's way, and I haven't tested your code.
Do you suggest that what you wrote here can replace everything else? It seems neater than what I put together (mildly OCD, I like neat )
Thanks for clarifying this, and thanks again for taking the time in answering!!

Answer (score 0):

Apropos. Since you are learning to code.

These loops to make and fill an array with some values from another array:

```
for (var i = 0, len = sheets.length, names = []; i < len; i++)
    names.push(sheets[i].getName());
```

Can be replaces with a short line:

```
var names = sheets.map(x => x.getName());
```

It look cleaner and easier as soon as you get used to it.

Comment: and thanks for this too, I replaced the string and it works like a charm. The only odd thing is that after duplicating all tabs, when I try to open any tab, I get a rather worrying notification that says "cannot load content, try to refresh" or something of the sort, but after refreshing the page everything works just fine.
Thanks again, I'm overwhelmed with joy 

Comment: Actually, probably just a glitch, I run it again and no error messages whatsoever, it just plain works. Thanks again 